# enum in struct compile error

Tags: c++, enums, struct

as title said,the code blow gives error with g++:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘logType’
```

Code:

```
enum 
{
     log_memory,
     log_filesystem,
     log_default
}logType;

typedef struct
{
     logType type;
     void (*logPrint)(char* msg);

}logsystem;
```

Comment: By the way, in C++ the `typedef` trick for `struct`s is not necessary. Just write `struct logsystem { ... };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
enum
{
    ...
} logType;
```

declares a *variable*, not a *type*.  You want this:

```
enum logType
{
    ...
};
```

[*Side-note: Usual C++ conventions are to have type-names start with a capital letter.*]

Answer (score 2):

When declaring an `enum` you specify the name of it right after the word `enum`, it's not like using `typedef` to create an alias for a struct.

```
enum logType
{
     log_memory,
     log_filesystem,
     log_default
};
```